# A differentiable function such that a tangent to its graph is also normal to the graph

Tags: calculus

> Let $f$ be a continuous, differentiable, an bijective function.  If the tangent to $y=f(x)$ at $x=a$ is also the normal to $y=f(x)$ at $x=b$, then there exists at least one $c \in (a,b)$ such that:
>
> (a) $f'(c)=0$
>
> (b) $f'(c)>0$
>
> (c) $f'(c)<0$
>
> (d) none of these.

Comment: I bet you could draw a line $L$ with two different points $P,Q$ on $L$ , and then draw a curve which is tangent to $L$ at $P$ and crosses $L$ at rignt angles at $Q$.

Comment: @LeeMosher I'm pretty sure that curve wont be a _bijective_ function.

Comment: I guess (d) is right since f doesn't exist in the first place?

Comment: Your OP states the opposite of what i just said

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $f'(a)f'(b)=-1$, so $f'(a)$ and $f'(b)$ have different signs. Even though $f'$ need not be continouos, it has the intermediate value property. Thus if we assume that the interval $[a,b]$ is part of the domain of $f$, then we find $c$ with $f'(c)<0$ and another $c$ with $f'(c)>0$ near $a$ or $b$ (which where depends on the signs) and $c$ with $f'(c)<0$ somewhere inbetween.

However, the assumption that $f$ is bijective tells us that this *cannot* be case!
Here's an example showing that (d) may happen:
Let $a=0$ and $b=1$ and consider $f\colon [-1,a]\cup [b,2)\to[-1,2]$ with 
$$f(x)=\begin{cases} x&\text{if $x\le a$}\\2-x&\text{if $x\ge b$}\end{cases} $$
This assume of course that your local definition of tangent/normal is compatible with taking the derivative at a boundary point of the function domain.